# nopcommerce 3.7 not get logged in from query string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, nopcommerce

I want to use query string for login in nopcommerce using login api i created. i want to just hit my method using query string and redirect to user dashboard. i create simple login method and inside that i used exact that code which used by nopcommerce for login. after using query string and hit enter then login method of api get hited all lines execute successfully but its not redirect to user dashboard as logged in.it redirect the same page without login.  here is my code

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Login(string username, string password)
    {
       var loginResult =_customerRegistrationService.ValidateCustomer(username,password);

        //
       switch (loginResult)
       {
           case CustomerLoginResults.Successful://get in here. 
               {
                   var customer = _customerSettings.UsernamesEnabled ? _customerService.GetCustomerByUsername(username) : _customerService.GetCustomerByEmail(username);

                   //migrate shopping cart
                   _shoppingCartService.MigrateShoppingCart(_workContext.CurrentCustomer, customer, true);

                   //sign in new customer
                    _authenticationService.SignIn(customer,false);

                   //raise event       
                   _eventPublisher.Publish(new CustomerLoggedinEvent(customer));

                   //activity log
                   _customerActivityService.InsertActivity("PublicStore.Login", _localizationService.GetResource("ActivityLog.PublicStore.Login"), customer);

                   //if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) || !Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
                   return RedirectToRoute("HomePage");

                   //return Redirect(returnUrl);
               }
           case CustomerLoginResults.CustomerNotExist:
               ModelState.AddModelError("", _localizationService.GetResource("Account.Login.WrongCredentials.CustomerNotExist"));
               break;
           case CustomerLoginResults.Deleted:
               ModelState.AddModelError("", _localizationService.GetResource("Account.Login.WrongCredentials.Deleted"));
               break;
           case CustomerLoginResults.NotActive:
               ModelState.AddModelError("", _localizationService.GetResource("Account.Login.WrongCredentials.NotActive"));
               break;
           case CustomerLoginResults.NotRegistered:
               ModelState.AddModelError("", _localizationService.GetResource("Account.Login.WrongCredentials.NotRegistered"));
               break;
           case CustomerLoginResults.WrongPassword:
           default:
               ModelState.AddModelError("", _localizationService.GetResource("Account.Login.WrongCredentials"));
               break;
       }

       if (loginResult.ToString()=="Successful")
       {
            return Successful(loginResult);
       }
       else
       {
           return ErrorOccured("Wrong Credentials");
       }


    }
```

Comment: please provide your user dashboard url in comments so i can fix your code

Comment: i.e:http://localhost:50421/Api/Login?username=admin@yourStore.com&password=9823531377

Comment: my url is localhost:50421/Api/Login?username=admin@yourStore.com&password=9823531377

Comment: Please tell me what happen on `Successful(loginResult);` and `ErrorOccured("Wrong Credentials");`?